# Error In authorize.net payment gateway in ssl certificate

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am working in php,Just integrated **authorize payment gateway**

I followed following link 
[Php Integration Guide](http://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/)

and then I have downloaded this
[Php-SDK Example](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php)

but whenever I execute this it shows me the error,I have checked the log and it shows me that 
**ERROR: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**.
please provide me the certain solution.

-**charge-credit-card.php**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;

define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog");

// Common setup for API credentials
$merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
$merchantAuthentication->setName("API-key");
$merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey("Trans-Key");
$refId = 'ref' . time();

// Create the payment data for a credit card
$creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
$creditCard->setCardNumber("370000000000002");
$creditCard->setExpirationDate("2038-12");
$paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
$paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);

// Create a transaction
$transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
$transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");
$transactionRequestType->setAmount(151.51);
$transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);
$request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
$request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
$request->setRefId($refId);
$request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);
$controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
$response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);

if ($response != null) {
    $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
    if (($tresponse != null) && ($tresponse->getResponseCode() == "1")) {
        echo "Charge Credit Card AUTH CODE : " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
        echo "Charge Credit Card TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "Charge Credit Card ERROR :  Invalid response\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Charge Credit Card Null response returned";
}
?>
```

**Error Message :** Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error getting valid response from api. Check log file for error details'

**In Log FIle**
**ERROR:** SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, It is Secure Socket Layer , mainly used to keep sensitive information sent across the Internet Encrypted so that only the intended recipient can understand it.
TO Remove SSL : navigate to lib/net/authorize/util/HttpClient.php
Line no 68 or nearby add the following

```
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE)
```

and run your file.

Comment: Future readers: don't do this! First of all, you're disabling encryption on a financial transaction. Second of all, you're modifying vendor code (which means that the "fix" will break again if you update or reinstall the library).

Comment: @greenie2600 any other fix? I just installed my SSL and now I am getting this error.